# Error: in [Seize]->Timeout->[Release]: Expecting a single value: [extent=11]

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using R simmer to do a simulation. However, I receive this error message every time when I run it:

> Error: 'truck0' at 48.73 in [Seize]->Timeout->[Release]:  Expecting a
>   single value: [extent=11].

What is wrong with this?

This is my R script:

```
rm(list=ls())
#load packages
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)

#create an simulation environment
env <- simmer("Terminal")
env

#create a truck trajectory
truck <- trajectory("Truck path", verbose = TRUE) 
truck  

#draw model
truck %>%

  seize("frontdesk",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(11.27671,3.233562)) %>% 
  release("frontdesk",1) %>%

  seize("gate-in",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(17.54509,9.915719)) %>% 
  release("gate-in",1) %>%

  seize("station",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(12.68418,12.55247)) %>% 
  release("station",1) %>%

  seize("lashing",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(28.87726,21.0809)) %>% 
  release("lashing",1) %>%

  seize("control",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(12.70417,3.711475)) %>% 
  release("control",1) %>%

  seize("frontdesk end",1) %>%
  timeout(function()rnorm(11.27671,3.233562)) %>%
  release("frontdesk end",1)

env <- lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  simmer("Terminal") %>%
    add_resource("frontdesk", 2) %>%
    add_resource("gate-in", 2) %>%
    add_resource("station", 1) %>%
    add_resource("lashing", 15) %>%
    add_resource("control", 1) %>%
    add_resource("frontdesk end", 2) %>%
    add_generator(name = "truck" , 
                  trajectory = truck,
                  distribution = function() rnorm(1,24.992,36.015)) %>%
    run(660) %>%
    wrap()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, timeout activities expect a single value, and you are providing 11 in this case. Because of this:

```
timeout(function() rnorm(11.27671,3.233562))
```

`rnorm`'s first parameter is the number of samples (which is rounded to 11 in this case). What are you trying to do here? If that's supposed to be `mean=11.27`, `sd=3.23`, then you need to add

```
timeout(function() rnorm(1, 11.27671,3.233562))
```

so that you get a single sample per call, as required. And the same applies for all the other timeouts.

EDIT: Also, I do not recommend using a normal distribution for service times, because a normal distribution may return negative values (that are by default coerced to positive), and thus you may get unexpected results.